# change button text color in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs5

I need to change text color of my button. I defined a css class like;

```
.mbutton{
    background:transparent;
    color:red;
    border:none;
}
```

and button definition is here;

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            text: 'Red text',
            cls:'mbutton'
   });
```

fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/olj

Comment: You tried `color: red !important;`?

Comment: didn't work, I've share sample code on fiddle and update post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `button` is generated with `span` elements inside. The `color` need to be changed in `span` instead in `button`. Do this way:

```
.mbutton span{
    color:red;
}
```